# Why my Code to convert Date time to date fails with different path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, datetime, timestamp

I tried below code with:

This path: (WORKS) `"/dbfs/mnt/datalake/.../ProductPages/"` `O/P- 2020-05-29`

This Path:(FAILS) `"/dbfs/mnt/datalake/.../LMMS16005/"`

Error: `time data 'Wed Dec 11 10:18:22 2019' does not match format '%a %B %d %H:%M:%S %Y'`

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

root = "/dbfs/mnt/datalake/.../LMMS16005/"
a = time.ctime(max(os.path.getmtime(root) for root,_,_ in os.walk(root))) 
aa = datetime.strptime(a,'%a %B %d %H:%M:%S %Y').date() 
print(aa)
```

Comment: Because `%B` matches the full month -- it's looking for "December". Your first test case is in May, which will match `%b` or `%B`. That does not work for "Dec" / "December" however.

Comment: Unrelated to your specific question, but you can also replace the epoch -> date string -> datetime -> date logic with [date.fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the format in the "datetime.strptime" function needs some change. Please change the code as below and give a try.

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

root = "/dbfs/mnt/datalake/.../LMMS16005/"
a = time.ctime(max(os.path.getmtime(root) for root,_,_ in os.walk(root))) 
aa = datetime.strptime(a,'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y').date() 
print(aa)
```